# Why does printf() with %f lose a digit after decimal point sometimes?

Tags: c, linux

Why does the statement

```
printf("%f", sensorvalue)
```

print out a string like “11312.96” (with two digits after decimal points) most of the time, but sometimes print out a string like “11313.1” (with one digit after decimal point)? `sensorvalue` is read from a power meter continuously. The values at different times are supposed to have the same format.

It's C running on Linux.

Comment: If you want a fixed number of fractional digits, then you need to include that in your format specifier, e.g. `%.2f`.

Comment: Please post the code used to print the output. Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `%f` exactly as stated, this actually violates the standard (this would be unusual but certainly not unheard of), which states in `C11 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function /8`:

> ***F, f:*** A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style `[−]ddd.ddd`, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as `6`.

In other words, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double d1 = 11312.96, d2 = 11313.1;
    printf("%f\n%f\n", d1, d2);
    return 0;
}
```

should generate:

```
11312.960000
11313.100000
```

---

If you *want* it to have a different format (in both your seemingly incorrect case, and the case that complies with the standard), use the precision argument to force it, such as with:

```
printf("%.2f\n", d1);    // gives "11312.96"
```

You may also want to specify the minimum field width to ensure your numbers are lined up on the right, such as with:

```
                          // posn:  123456789
                          //        ---------
printf("%9.2f\n", d1);    // gives " 11312.96"
printf("%9.2f\n", 3.1);   // gives "     3.10"
```

Comment: The sensorvalue is actually from reading of a sensor device. It data type is float. I just doubt whether the sensor device sends reading with different precision in different time. Surely, it sounds weird. 
I know the way to specify its precision like %.2f, but I just don't know the coming value's precision in advance. That is the reason why I used '%f" and expect at least the shown precision should be the same in each time reading.

Comment: @Stan, yes it should be the same. The fact that it's not means your C library is deficient. But, whether you explicitly state two decimal places or allow the implicit six (or some arbitrary number in your case), you *are* making the decision. You may as well do it explicitly, and exert some control.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the statement `printf("%f", sensorvalue)` print out the string like 11312.96 (with two digits after decimal points) at most time, but sometimes print string like 11313.1 (with one digit after decimal point)?

The library is simply not C compliant even if "It's C running on Linux."

The output of

```
printf("%f\n", 11312.96f);
printf("%f\n", 11312.96);
printf("%f\n", 11313.1f);
printf("%f\n", 11313.1);
```

... is expected to be like the below with 6 digits after the `'.'` - perhaps with some variation in the values of the least digits.  Even with implementations of varying quality, the output should have been **6** digits after the `'.'`.

```
11312.959961
11312.960000
11313.099609
11313.100000
```

Had the format been `"%g"`, output like below could have occurred.

```
11313
11313
11313.1
11313.1
```